# Does a range of cells contain a value in a list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to answer - does a range of cells (A1:E1) contain any value from a list (G1:G50)

In other words: Does A1 OR B1 OR C1 OR D1 OR E1 contain any value that appears in G1:G50?

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($A$1:$E$1,$G$1:$G$50))>=1
```

will return TRUE or FALSE for your conditions

Comment: clever. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a match function. In A2 put -

```
MATCH(A1,$G$1:$G$50,0)
```

Drag this across row 2, and it will return a value (the row number) if it's found in both lists. If it's not found, it will give you `#N/A`

Then you could, for instance, put in a formula like `=ISNA(A1:E1)` as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shft</kbd> <kbd>Entr</kbd>) and FALSE would indicate if any were found, otherwise TRUE.